# Project Web App (Sharepoint 2010) - Error when adding a new user

Tags: project-server, ms-project, pwa

After navigating to `"Server Settings" -> "Manage Users"`.

I select "`New User`" options, where I enter necessary information (tried many variations - same as existing users/other).

After clicking "`Save`" Button, I receive the following error:

The resource could not be saved due to the following reasons:

> • An unknown error has occurred.

Comment: are you seeing any error in the Event log?

Comment: only warning - "Alternate access mappings have not been configured. "

Comment: are you accessing it with FQDN or servername and port number?

Comment: servername and port number

Comment: also since port 80 is occupied, we are using other port for sharepoint and pwa, for external access.

Comment: configurations.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brismith/archive/2010/07/02/project-server-2010-an-unknown-error-has-occurred-in-project-center-resource-center-or-tasks.aspx) you have to make sure following settings for web app is configured properly.

The issue was that in IIS Manager the Authentication for the site was set to use Windows Authentication, but in the Advanced Settings, Extended Protection was set to a value other than Off. Please Set it to **Off**.

[image]

Comment: I don't have "extended protection" option available, only option to enable kernel-mode authentication. I am able to log-in with 2 accounts that are in the list of users.